# Connect to DB2 using ibm_db , connection attempt starts but never finish

Tags: python, db2, azure-databricks, db2-400

trying to connect to Ibm DB2 with ibm_db in Python, Im running it on Azure Databricks.
I get through to the DB2 but the connection just hangs there for a while until it end with an error.

```
from ibm_db import connect

connection = connect('DATABASE=MyDB;HOSTNAME=MyHost;PORT=MyPort;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=MyUid;PWD=MyPwd', '', '')
```

I get after a while the error:

[IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "MyIp".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "110", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081

On the DB2 side they can see the connection attempt as:

SYN-received
Waiting for a confirming connection request
acknowledgment.

Now the DB2 has a package collection that is perhaps needed, I cant seem to find the syntax to add this to the connection string however.

The other suspect is azure databricks but has no clue in what way.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the Db2-platform for the Db2-server? Z/os, i-series,  linux/unix/windows/cloud ?    Have you checked with the DBA whether the connection must be encrypted with SSL/TLS?   Have you checked if a certificate is required to authenticate?

Comment: Hi @mao . IBMi(i-series), SSL only by choise, and no certificate is required.

Comment: For connecting to i-series, you should use (at your azur client side) the IBM i access product with it's odbc option.    That seems to work best.   Currently you appear to be using clidriver, which will __either__ need a license file, or you will connect via a Db2-connect gateway.    Fixing the tags to specify db2-400 to indicate i-series.

Comment: Hmm using databricks makes it hard to use installable products and I would like to be able to use Python for this. In Data factory the connection works as it should, do that service use another driver perhaps ? I tried to specify the driver   DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER} but with the same result , is this the clidriver ?

Comment: The error message mentions the driver (`[IBM][CLI Driver] `) which corresponds to `{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}`. The error code 110 is a timeout, usually a network problem.. Verify the port-number, and that no firewalls are blocking traffic on that port between your azur client and the i-series.

Comment: So the databricks enviroment was set up wrongly, the DB cluster could access the DB2 but the response was stopped. Then of cource I run into: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1598N  An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem.  SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598.

Comment: as I mentioned in a previous comment, clidriver requires licensing (only when accessing i-series or z/os)  but the  `IBM i access` with odbc option does not. This is a configuration matter, it is not a programming matter, so the question is off topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi mao , I totally agree just mentioned the end result. Thanks for all the input!